# Run shell script in Windows without Cygwin/requiring downloads from clients

Tags: batch-file, cygwin, dos, portability, csh

I'm working on converting software that runs in the Mac/Unix environment (C Shell scrips) into something Windows can handle. When we release the Windows version, the team don't want to make users download anything outside what we ship to use the software, which counts out using portability software like Cygwin and better-suited scripting languages like python.

Googling for a windows csh interpreter we could ship with the code came up dry. The few projects I found along these lines are limited to simulating the Unix environment on a user's computer. **Is there an easy way to use bash scripts in software running in Windows, potentially with some code we can ship with it?** Compile it naively, steal Cygwin's interpreter, whatever solution works.

The code automates iterating through a number of different inputs to our software, involving file manipulation and math, but doesn't have any external dependencies. This script is updated occasionally from outside the company, so the solution should ideally be applicable for future scripts.

I'd *really* like to avoid translating hundreds of lines of complicated csh commands to DOS by hand.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to use bash scripts in software running in Windows, potentially with some code we can ship with it?

You can take a look at [UnxTools](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) which is old, but still works pretty well. It has a `sh` shell which can be used for your purposes.

Otherwise, you might need to use Cygwin to accomplish what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are Windows versions of `tcsh` [alongside the *NIX sources](http://www.tcsh.org/MostRecentRelease), as well as a Windows port of `zsh` named [WinZsh](http://zsh-nt.sourceforge.net/WinZsh).  YMMV

Comment: I don't see the links for either--the first doesn't have any windows downloads and the second link is broken.

Comment: The first link offers several mirrors of the current release; choose one and look for `*-x86.exe.gz` or `*-x64.exe.gz` for Win32 or Win64, respectively.  As for the second link, I just fixed it.